# UnsupportedOperationException JSF - webLogic 11g

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

I'm developing a web application and I'm using the following versions:

- spring-core 3.1.3
- spring-webmvc 3.1.3
- spring-webflow 2.3.1
- spring-faces 2.3.1
- jsf-api 2.0.9
- jsf-impl 2.0.9
- java 1.6

The application is deployed in a WebLogic server 10.3.6. 
Randomly , the exception shown below is thrown while I am navigating through the application.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getPartialViewContext(FacesContext.java:165)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfAjaxHandler.isAjaxRequestInternal(JsfAjaxHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.js.ajax.AbstractAjaxHandler.isAjaxRequest(AbstractAjaxHandler.java:19)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.createServletExternalContext(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.jeveris.web.core.filter.log.PerformanceLogFilter.doFilter(PerformanceLogFilter.java:59)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

An example of a bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class bean implements Serializable{
 ...
}
```

An example of a flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    parent="parent-flow" start-state="searchDashboardState">

<on-start>          
    <evaluate expression="dashboardController.clean(flowRequestContext)" />
</on-start> 


<view-state id="searchDashboardState" view="../views/dashboard/searchDashboardView.xhtml">

    <transition on="search" to="searchDashboardState">
          <evaluate expression="dashboardController.find(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.dashboardData" result-type="dataModel"/>
    </transition>

</view-state>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting people to do for you here. There is a full stack trace and you need to go step by step through it to figure out what went wrong. No one has the code this stack trace is referring to except you.

Comment: This is a weird case because sometimes works and sometimes throw the exception. The only point clear is that this exception is thrown because the defaultFacesContext is null.

Comment: Do you somehow have more than one version of `javax.faces.context.FacesContext` on your classpath? That call does exist in Java 1.6 https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getPartialViewContext() It does not exist in 1.5 https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html

Comment: What I did was to exclude jstl from the pom and it worked!!! <exclusion>        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
</exclusion>